# Oracle VM VirtualBox starts VM when open Remotesession (via RDP)

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am running Oracle VM VirtualBox 6.0.11 on a Windows 7 host. When I open a remotesession (via RDP) to the Windows 7 host, the guest VM starts sometimes (VM starts in background without GUI).

I have no idea why. I didn't find any option in VirtualBox for WakeOnLan or something else. Is this a bug or can I configure this?